# Aggregating sales, count of transactions by age range and gender to get a pivot

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 SELECT CASE 
     WHEN age BETWEEN 1 AND 25 THEN '1-25' 
     WHEN age BETWEEN 26 AND 35 THEN '26-35' 
     WHEN age BETWEEN 36 AND 45 THEN '36-45' 
     WHEN age BETWEEN 46 AND 55 THEN '46-55' 
     WHEN age >= 56 THEN '56+' 
   END  AS Age_Range, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END) AS "M Count", 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END) AS "F Count", 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN gender = 'Unk' THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END) AS "Unk Count" 
FROM   dm_owner.v_individualbrand 
WHERE  Trunc(txn_date) BETWEEN '01-JAN-18' AND '31-DEC-18' 
   AND brandcode = 'HT' 
GROUP  BY CASE 
        WHEN age BETWEEN 1 AND 25 THEN '1-25' 
        WHEN age BETWEEN 26 AND 35 THEN '26-35' 
        WHEN age BETWEEN 36 AND 45 THEN '36-45' 
        WHEN age BETWEEN 46 AND 55 THEN '46-55' 
        WHEN age >= 56 THEN '56+' 
      END 
 ORDER  BY age_range;
```

I am trying to add 2 more columns which are the count of transactions and total sales. My table should look like:

[image]

Comment: Please show what your table looks like and sample data.

Comment: So you just need to repeat your existing `sum()` calls, but change one to a `count()`, and the other to sum the sales amount instead of the fixed `1` you have now? What problems are you encountering changing your code to get those results?

Comment: I am sorry, this is the first time I am using this forum and I am not sure how it works !

Comment: @AlexPoole my count of individuals is inflating. The total count of individuals before adding the sales and count of txns is 7.2 million and after the revised query the count of individuals for male, female and unk total rise to 52 million this is the query I changes:

count(CASE WHEN gender_description = 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS "M Count",
 Sum(CASE WHEN gender_description = 'Male' THEN dollar_value_us ELSE 0 END) AS "M Sales"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extend your conditional aggregate.  Your current counts would seem to be transaction counts, unless that is a separate column in the table.

The query would be like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 1 AND 25 THEN '1-25' 
             WHEN age BETWEEN 26 AND 35 THEN '26-35' 
             WHEN age BETWEEN 36 AND 45 THEN '36-45' 
             WHEN age BETWEEN 46 AND 55 THEN '46-55' 
             WHEN age >= 56 THEN '56+' 
        END) as Age_Range, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "M Count",
       Sum(CASE WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS "M Sales",
       Sum(CASE WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "F Count", 
       Sum(CASE WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS "F Sales", 
       Sum(CASE WHEN gender = 'Unk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Unk Count" 
       Sum(CASE WHEN gender = 'Unk' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS "Unk Sales" 
FROM dm_owner.v_individualbrand 
WHERE txn_date >= DATE '2018-01-01' AND
      txn_date < DATE '2019-01-01' AND
      brandcode = 'HT' 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 1 AND 25 THEN '1-25' 
               WHEN age BETWEEN 26 AND 35 THEN '26-35' 
               WHEN age BETWEEN 36 AND 45 THEN '36-45' 
               WHEN age BETWEEN 46 AND 55 THEN '46-55' 
               WHEN age >= 56 THEN '56+' 
          END)
ORDER BY MIN(age);
```

Comment: I have a separate coloumn of transaction numbers and I am trying to get a count of all the distinct transaction numbers

Comment: I used your code and its inflating my numbers :( the number of individuals is 7.2 milions in total when I use this query the count of individuals rise to 52 million

Comment: @SomiyaL . . . This should be returning the same counts that you are getting.  Your query is counting transactions (presumably) and so is this.